# Jquery cycling through array - there must be a better way

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I've seen questions similar to this one and I've read and re-read them over the last couple of days. I just don't know if I'm doing this correctly (I highly doubt that I am) and how to get from here to the correct method. Basically I have an array full of images that I'd like to cycle through. It's working but for some reason the value of c is zero twice consecutively.

```
function slider_plus() {
    var imgs = imgArr.length;

    a++;
    var b = a - 1;
    var c = a + 1;

    if (a >= imgs) {
        a = 0;
    }
    if (b < 0) {
        b = imgs - 1;
    }
    if (c >= imgs) {
        c = 0;
    }
    $("#varsDiv").html(" var b = " + b + " var a = " + a + " var c = " + c);
    $("#basic_ul").html(imgArr[b] + imgArr[a] + imgArr[c]);
}
```

In other words the value of c should increase each time the function is called. But when instead these are the results for calling the function repeatedly: 2 3 0 0 1 2 3 0 0 1 2 3 0 0... and so on. I need it to just be: 2 3 0 1 2 3 0 1. I am 100% sure that there is a better way to do this but I'm a noob and this is as far as I've gotten...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The quick fix to your code is to adjust `a` (setting it to 0 when its >= `imgs`) before you set and adjust the values of `b` and `c`. Right now when `a` loops around you set both it and `c` to 0, which I don't think is what you want.

You also might want to read up on the modulus operator, `%`. It will let you "wrap" those values around more easily.

```
a %= imgs // will set a to 0 when it equals imgs
```

You'll still have to catch that -1 case for `b`, though.

Comment: Thanks @bhamlin! I will study up on the modulus operator, perhaps I can cut down a great deal of my code with that.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean like this?

```
var a = 0;
function slider_plus() {
    var imgs = imgArr.length;
    $("#basic_ul").html(imgArr[a++ % imgs] + imgArr[a % imgs] + imgArr[(a+1) % imgs]);
}
```